# Setting objects coordinates in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using tkinter but I can't find anyway to set coordinates of my objects. In python docs just using of side is mentioned. Is there a way to say left and top of my objects in a window?
For example:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.constants import *
tk = tkinter.Tk()
frame = tkinter.Frame(tk, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=2)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
label = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Hello, World")
label.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
button = tkinter.Button(frame,text="Exit",command=tk.destroy)#here I need to put my button at left=0,top=10 !!!
button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `place()` in place of `pack()`. But don't use `pack()`, `grid()`, `place()` in the same `Frame` at the same time. Of course you can use (for example) `pack()` in parent `Frame` and `grid()` in child `Frame`.

see: [Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), [Pack Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm), [Place Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)